# Combining regex matches

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to combine those 5 regex to one (or at least some of them)?

```
/[ ,][ABCabc][:]\d+/g
/[ ,][ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+/g
/^[ABCabc][:]\d+/g
/^[ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+/g
/[\\][\w][ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+/g
```

Tips, corrections and improvments will be great as well.

Comment: An explanation of what they do would be helpful...

Comment: Do you mean **any of** those 5 or do you mean **all of** those 5?  That is, `/p1/ || /p2/ || /p3/ || /p4/ || /p5/` or `/p1/ && /p2/ && /p3/ && /p4/ && /p5/`? Or something else altogether?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, reduce them:

- `/[ ,][a-c]:\d+/gi`
- `/[ ,][a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`
- `/^[a-c]:\d+/gi`
- `/^[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`
- `/\\\w[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`

Now, by combining them, you mean you're testing for a match against any, not all, of them, right? So step 2:

- **`/[ ,][a-c](:| ?= ?)\d+/gi`**
- `/^[a-c]:\d+/gi`
- `/^[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`
- `/\\\w[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`

Step 3:

- `/[ ,][a-c](:| ?= ?)\d+/gi`
- **`/^[a-c](:| ?= ?)\d+/gi`**
- `/\\\w[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`

Step 4:

- **`/(^| |,)[a-c](:| ?= ?)\d+/gi`**
- `/\\\w[a-c] ?= ?\d+/gi`

Step 5:

- **`/((^| |,)[a-c](:| ?= ?)|\\\w[a-c] ?= ?)\d+/gi`**

Voilà. You could use captures for Step 5 but I won't complicate things.

If you can, stick with the result from Step 4. Step 5 makes the regex long and confusing.

Comment: You can even replace the groups with non-capturing groups to be consistent with the original expressions (and faster of course).

Comment: thank you very much, I've understood all but it is not working as i had expected, i use those regex in my array push: push (@match,/[ ,][$char$char2][:]\d+/g); , and now its give me in the match array only " : === : " like that..

Comment: @David: Yes, that's a side effect of combining them. You can use The Evil Greebo's solution instead if you're using the matches like that, or you can adapt the array indices you use to do that.

Comment: @minitech: Can you explain why it's not working? I've tried The Evil Greebo's solution, it's also not working?

Comment: @David: Okay, I'm a bit confused now - are you using the match results? In the array `@match`?

Comment: @David: Okay, so you need to adjust the indices you're using to match the regex. Anything within parenthesis in my regexes is a group, so you need to fix your method to use the appropriate groups. Just count the opening parentheses.

Comment: @minitech: still having problems.. can you write the regex?

Comment: @David: It's not a regex. If you want me to fix it, I need to see your entire code.

Comment: @David: Actually, judging by your code, try this: `push (@match[0], /[ ,][$char$char2][:]\d+/g);` instead.

Comment: @minitech: that's what I originally did

Answer (score 2):

you may want to take a look at `Regexp::Assemble`

Answer (score 0):

You could always combine regexes into one, just by (regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)... (If this is what you mean by "combine into one")

The question is whether you should, surely? Regexes are generally pretty hard to read as it is, and anything you can do to make them easier to understand and to modify in future is to be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

If by combine you mean regex test so that if any of the patterns match you get a match, yes:

```
(?:
    (?:/[ ,][ABCabc][:]\d+)|
    (?:/[ ,][ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+)|
    (?:/^[ABCabc][:]\d+)|
    (?:/^[ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+)|
    (?:/[\\][\w][ABCabc][ ]?[=][ ]?\d+)
)/g
```

Comment: Ay, caramba!  I don't even know where to start.  Just, no.

Comment: What a constructive response.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Hey, it works, and it's very clear but possibly more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that was kinda rude; sorry.  But the answer *is* wrong.  The way you've got it, it's as if the `/` and `/g` are part of the text you're trying to match, and I'm reasonably certain the slashes are meant as regex delimiters, and the `g` is the "global" modifier.  To combine the regexes the way you're trying to do, the result should look like this: `/(?:regex1)|(?:regex2)|(?:regex3)|(?:regex4)|(?:regex5)/g`.

Comment: Yeah you're right - I just did a real quick concatenation.  Fixed that much at least.